# Erro no reload, ts-node-dev e PrismaClient

Tags: node.js, typescript, back-end, prisma

Boa tarde meus amigos, tudo na paz?

Estou tendo querendo migrar uma pequena API para Prisma removendo o TypeORM.
Bom, até o momento consegui instalar e rodar sem problemas, MAS (normal, kkkk). Reparei que ao mexer em uma WHERE por exemplo, eu sou obrigado a restartar o docker para testar a alteração.

Por exemplo, seu salvar o código abaixo, vai funcionar sem problemas e retornar o JSON:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
// import { GetPriceListService } from '@services/commercial/price-lists/get';

const routes = Router();
routes.get('/:price_list_id/status', async (request, response) => {
  //
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const result = await prisma.price_lists.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: request.params.price_list_id,
      // status: 'aaaaa',
    },
  });

  //
  return response.json(result);
});
export default routes;
```

Mas, para adicionar um novo filtro 'status' no WHERE, eu salvo o arquivo, recebo a notificação no cosole que o memso foi alterado:

```
backend | [INFO] 15:26:43 Restarting: /home/node/app/src/routes/commercial/price-lists/status.ts has been modified
```

mas não funciona, tenho que restartar o container, para aplicar a alteração.

o meu script de start do package.json, está assim:

```
"dev:server": "ts-node-dev --inspect --transpile-only --ignore node_modules -r tsconfig-paths/register src/server.ts"
```

Desde já, meu muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia,

consegui descobrir o que estava acontecendo e resolver.

No momento que eu salvo a aplicação, o ts-node-dev "mata" a o processo filho e abre um novo processo. O ts-node-dev não estava conceguindo "matar" o processo pois o Prisma cria um outro processo(acredito que seja a conexão aberta do o banco de dados).

**Solução**

Adicionei um evento antes de iniciar a aplicação para forçar o fechamento.

```js
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  process.exit();
});
```

Obrigado!!!